# This function has a return type of 'String', but doesn't end with a return statement

Tags: flutter, dart

I got stuck with an error can anyone help me to solve this
"This function has a return type of 'String' but doesn't end with a return statement. Try adding a return statement, or changing the return type to 'void'.",

Under value it is underlined with the blue line(showing error)

```
TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'E-Mail'),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                  return 'Invalid email!';
                }
              },
              onSaved: (value) {
                _authData['email'] = value;
              },
           ),
```

Comment: Can you please paste your code **as code**. You can't even read it this way !!

Comment: You probably need to add a return for else part

Comment: i already tried with it ,still it shows error @JohnJoe

Comment: Can you post more code ? Include how you add `TextFormField` in widget build.

Comment: The error message shows all detail you happened. It might need to said: The function `validator`  has a ... Right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot to `return null` 
code snippet

```
validator: (value) {
            if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
              return 'Invalid email!';
            }
            return null;
          },
```

Comment: Returning `null` is not a good practice.

Comment: @Hamed, official document say:  If there are no errors, the validator must return null. https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation#2-add-a-textformfield-with-validation-logic

Comment: you are right, my bad. :)